# ASP Checkbox list inside hide/show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have a checkboxList within a Div. The div hide when click on H4 . but  I can't hide that div when click on H4 after select any of the checkbox item

Please check the following code I have used

```
<div class="prod-filter-nav">
<h4>Category</h4>
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1"  runat="server" class="prod-list"  
AutoPostBack="True"   RepeatLayout="UnorderedList">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
</div>
```

Javascript used for this page:--

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.prod-filter-nav h4').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('closed').siblings('.prod-list').slideToggle(300);
})
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: u can try something like this:<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1"  runat="server" class="prod-list"  
AutoPostBack="True"   RepeatLayout="UnorderedList" clientIdmode="Static">
</asp:CheckBoxList>

Answer (score 1):

Instead of finding a [sibling](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) of `<h4>` just find the [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) element.

```
$(function(e) {
    $('.prod-filter-nav h4').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('closed').next().slideToggle(300);
    })
});
```